# ROS Answers SE migration: 3DM-GX3-25 IMU

Tags: ros, imu, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a little unclear whether the imu_drivers stack supports the newer IMUs. In the summary, it claims to support both 3DM-GX2 and 3DM-GX3 protocols. However, further down it only speaks about the 3DM-GX2 protocol.

Are the newer devices supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29408/3dm-gx3-25-imu/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, 3DM-GX3 protocol is also supported (see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9704/any-microstrain-imu-driver-supporting-3dm-gx3)). I am using the [microstrain_3dmgx2_imu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu) package with Microstrain 3DM-GX3-25 IMU without any issues.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, at some point, there was a separate stack (or modifications to the GX2 stack) that we used with the GX3 version.

Now, we are using the imu_drivers version included with Electric as our driver for the 3DM-GX3-25, so I can say that it is supported.

I haven't done much investigation into all of the features of the driver, but I can say that it does output filtered orientation messages (as well as linear and angular velocity) at up to 200 Hz, from what I've seen.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1